# Simple Server for messenger

Tags: java

For a messenger program I am writing a `Server` class that will run a non-blocking server in one thread. A messenger thread will use this server thread to communicate with other clients.

#### What the server should do

- Accept connections from / connect to other instances of the server and associate the selection keys for the connections in `Map<Integer, SelectionKey> keys` wit an ID so the messenger thread can access the connections by ID
- Read from / write to connections
- Store incoming messages in a queue
- Messenger thread can

  - Fetch incoming messages
  - Queue messages to be sent: `send_message(int id, String msg)`

```
package snserver;

/* imports */

//class SNServer (Simple non-blocking Server)

public class SNServer extends Thread {
    private int port;
    private Selector selector;
    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, SelectionKey> keys; // ID -> associated key
    private ConcurrentMap<SocketChannel,List<byte[]>> dataMap_out;
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> in_msg; //incoming messages to be fetched by messenger thread

    public SNServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        dataMap_out = new ConcurrentHashMap<SocketChannel, List<byte[]>>();
        keys = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, SelectionKey>();
    }

    public void start_server() throws IOException {
        // create selector and channel
        this.selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // bind to port
        InetSocketAddress listenAddr = new InetSocketAddress((InetAddress)null, this.port);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddr);
        serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        log("Echo server ready. Ctrl-C to stop.");

        // processing
        while (true) {
            // wait for events
            this.selector.select();

            // wakeup to work on selected keys
            Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();

                // this is necessary to prevent the same key from coming up 
                // again the next time around.
                keys.remove();

                if (! key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                }
                else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key);
                }
                else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    this.write(key);
                }
                else if(key.isConnectable()) {
                    this.connect(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        send_message(key, "Welcome."); //DEBUG

        Socket socket = channel.socket();
        SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
        log("Connected to: " + remoteAddr);

        // register channel with selector for further IO
        dataMap_out.put(channel, new ArrayList<byte[]>());
        channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        //store key in 'keys' to be accessable by ID from messenger thread //TODO first get ID
        keys.put(0, key);
    }

    //TODO verify, test
    public void init_connect(String addr, int port){
        try {
            SocketChannel channel = createSocketChannel(addr, port);
            channel.register(this.selector, channel.validOps()/*, SelectionKey.OP_?*/);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO handle
        }
    }

    //TODO verify, test
    private void connect(SelectionKey key) {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        try {
            channel.finishConnect(); //try to finish connection - if 'false' is returned keep 'OP_CONNECT' registered
            //store key in 'keys' to be accessable by ID from messenger thread //TODO first get ID
            keys.put(0, key);
        }
        catch (IOException e0) {
            try {
                //TODO handle ok?
                channel.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                //TODO handle
            }
        }

    }

    private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        int numRead = -1;
        try {
            numRead = channel.read(buffer);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (numRead == -1) {
            this.dataMap_out.remove(channel);
            Socket socket = channel.socket();
            SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
            log("Connection closed by client: " + remoteAddr); //TODO handle
            channel.close();
            return;
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[numRead];
        System.arraycopy(buffer.array(), 0, data, 0, numRead);
        in_msg.add(new String(data, "utf-8"));
    }

    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        List<byte[]> pendingData = this.dataMap_out.get(channel);
        Iterator<byte[]> items = pendingData.iterator();
        while (items.hasNext()) {
            byte[] item = items.next();
            items.remove();
            //TODO is this correct? -> re-doing write in loop with same buffer object
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(item);
            int bytes_to_write = buffer.capacity();
            while (bytes_to_write > 0) {
                bytes_to_write -= channel.write(buffer);
            }
        }
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    public void queue_data(SelectionKey key, byte[] data) {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        List<byte[]> pendingData = this.dataMap_out.get(channel);
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

        pendingData.add(data);
    }

    public void send_message(int id, String msg) {
        SelectionKey key = keys.get(id);
        if (key != null)
            send_message(key, msg);
        //else
            //TODO handle
    }

    public void send_message(SelectionKey key, String msg) {
        try {
            queue_data(key, msg.getBytes("utf-8"));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            //is not thrown: utf-8 is always defined
        }
    }

    public String get_message() {
        return in_msg.poll();
    }

    private static void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            start_server();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
            //TODO handle exception
        }
    }    


    // Creates a non-blocking socket channel for the specified host name and port.
    // connect() is called on the new channel before it is returned.
    public static SocketChannel createSocketChannel(String hostName, int port) throws IOException {
        // Create a non-blocking socket channel
        SocketChannel sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        sChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Send a connection request to the server; this method is non-blocking
        sChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostName, port));
        return sChannel;
    }
}
```

#### General problem

Because I am new to Java and networking there may be several things incorrect or not good in this code. Please help me improve this code so it does what I'd like it to do. Also give suggestions to improve the concept!

#### Current problems:

- After calling `init_connect()` there seems to be no event on the selector so the connection is not built.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I came across a nice library for doing network stuff in Java called [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). It's not even a library - it is rather a framework for building scalable apps, so it imposes some architecture decisions on application architecture. Even though using it might be an overkill in your situation I suggest you to check its docs out as you might learn the approaches implemented there.

What I can see can be improved:

- **Code layering**. In your code you have everything in one place: network handling, packet queuing and so on. So it is difficult to see which is where, to test and debug it. I'd try to separate the layers somehow.
- **Separation of network and business logic threads**. In-case your business logic or I/O gets significantly more load then the counterpart the whole performance will degrade since it is done in a single thread. This might be not an issue in this particular case since the logic is rather simple, but nevertheless. If you move the business logic into a separate thread I/O won't block waiting for it to perform its work and the overall performance will increase. The pitfall is the proper communication/synchronization between the threads so that they don't thrash the data.

The points above are pretty much handled in that lib, so I suggest you to peek into their docs and examples to understand the rationale and the way they implemented it. Even if you won't opt for it you might learn something useful for your project.

P.S.: I'm not affiliated neither with JBoss nor with netty, but I really fell in love with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with networking, so I cannot criticize the logic itself, alas. I have some minor remarks on the form, though:

- It is controversial because you will find some people proponent of this style, but I personally (and it is shared by many people!) avoid to use `this.fieldName` outside of constructors, because it is redundant. I see it as visual noise. It can help distinguishing local variables from fields, I chose to use a prefix for that, which is controversial too...
- `in_msg` field isn't declared private, not sure if it is intentional.
- Don't swallow the exception in `init_connect`, you might miss some problem...

That's most of what I can think of; you might need to clean up resources if you catch an exception at the level of `run()`.

Comment: Thanks that you try to help! 1) I normally do not use "this" but the code is based on examples of the internet and I didn't change everything. 2)+3) At the moment I am just trying to get the server working so I didn't really care about data encapsulation etc. Also see the "TODO"s in the code... I do not really know how to handle the exception in `init_connect` so I left it as a TODO. Anyway I'll change the code a little now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

Use a state machine.

#### Longer answer

I haven't read your code in detail, but I already worked with the Java's non-blocking sockets. So I can say it's pretty difficult to get it right.

I once inherited a codebase that was similar to your code. My task was to write unit tests, in order to be close to 100% branches coverage. I tried to write tests without touching the code, but there are so much states to track (the selector, the buffers, the socket's state) that I was not able to reliably test the code.

So, I re-wrote the code, using a state-machine to encapsulate these states. I ended up with 7 small classes, each one representing the state of the sockets, or the state of the request processing. The resulting code was more robust (many missing edge-cases became obvious), easier to understand and to maintain. Writing the tests was easier, then.

If I had to do it again, I'd try to use Netty (as Ihor suggested). Netty encapsulates the states too, and manages the connection errors in a more unified way.